# Vtiger - Jquery slideToggle randomly toggles twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, vtiger

I made a widget in the summary view of the account module. In this widget i want to use a slideToggle to show some details. Sometimes the code works perfectly but other times it double toggles and instantly closes the details.

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.potential_single_title').on('click',function(e) {
            $(this).parent().find('.potential_comment_list').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
```

TPL:

```
<script src="resources/ChildCommentScript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/ChildCommentStyle.css">

{strip}
    <div class="potential_comment_container">
    {foreach from=$OPP key=K item=POT}
        <br />
        <div class="potential_single">
            <div class="potential_single_title">
                <strong>{$POT[1]}</strong> <span class="potential_assignee">Assigned to : {$POT[2]}</span>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="potential_comment_list">
                <div class="commentContainer">
                {foreach from=$COM[$K] item=POTCOM}
                    <div class="commentDetails" style="width:100%;">
                        <div class="span1">
                            <img class="alignMiddle pull-left" src="layouts/vlayout/skins/images/DefaultUserIcon.png">
                        </div>
                        <span class="commentorName"><strong> {$POTCOM[0]}</strong></span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><p class="muted"><small>{$POTCOM[1]}</small></p></span>
                        <div class="commentInfoContent">{$POTCOM[2]}</div>
                    </div>
                {/foreach}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/foreach}
    </div>
{/strip}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of slide toggle seems to be correct. I suspect the click is happening twice sometimes which is causing slide again. 
Modifying JS to reject clicks if slide action is happening might resolve the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sliding = false;
    $('.potential_single_title').on('click',function(e) {
        if(sliding) return false;
        sliding = true;
        $(this).parent().find('.potential_comment_list').slideToggle('slow', function() {sliding = false;});
    });
});
```

Simple flag to reject click action while sliding is included!

Comment: Thnx for answering but unfortunately the div still gets double toggled at times. If i refresh a couple of times it works fine again. It might conflicting with  Vtiger's own JS files or maybe it happens because the page is made by php using the .tpl file and this some how loads it twice.

Comment: yeah the js seems ok, may i suggest you put some debugging in to see if the onclick is firing twice..ie clicked twice or if it is, indeed an issue with the js

Comment: wait is it not that you have the protental for more than one "potential_single_title" element on the page at any given time... this would toggle them all given that its in a **{foreach from=$OPP key=K item=POT}**

Comment: @Seabizkit how would i be able to check if its clicked twice? I did try debugging by inserting console logs before and after the slide toggle. On one click i got the before and after message twice. This is kinda like a q&a page where you click on the question to see the answer. Also this functions well because im looking for a specific class in side potential single. the for loop makes multiple potential_single and when the potential_single_title gets clicked it toggles the potential_comment_list.

Comment: I removed the document ready and now this works. thnx @Lohith.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to show how to see if the click is happening twice.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.potential_single_title').on('click',function(e) {
                console.log("clicked")
            });
        });
```

for one click.. if in console you see clicked twice you can assume your trigger happy ;-)

try also putting a debugger in there... may highlight things

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.potential_single_title').on('click',function(e) {
                    console.log("clicked");
debugger;
                });
            });
```

in chrome the debugger console must be open for it to hit the debugger line.

just want to rule out stupid things.. this is one for one what is on the page no other js... like maybe your wrapping $(document).ready( twice or something and just havnt included that code in the question?

Comment: Apparently im trigger happy because i get clicked twice with one click. As for you question, this is all of the JS in this file. There is more JS used on the page but thats is a standard vtiger JS file

Comment: you told me about the document ready so i removed it just to see what happens and now @lohith 's answer works. thnx for helping dude.